# Running docker command from bash in running container

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker

I'm working on a docker C# application, that logs in to Azure Container Registry and then executes docker pull and docker tag over some files from the registry. I tried to use a Process to execute a /bin/bash file with arguments corresponding to required command, like "-c \"docker pull filename\"", but I get a docker: command not found. Is there a way to run docker command outside the container or any other better way to do this?

Edit:

This is how I call the first command docker login, where after process.Start() I get `/bin/bash: docker: command not found`:

```
var command = $"docker login {endpointBaseUri} -u {login} -p {password}";

Process process = new Process()
{
  StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
  {
    FileName = "/bin/bash",           
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    Arguments = $"-c \"{command}\"";
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
  }
};

process.Start();

string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Showing some code would make it a lot easier to get to a solution.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel added to the question, should be more clear now

Comment: maybe before running docker, first you should install it on the same `bash` then execute docker command?

Comment: probably you're looking for docker in docker or docker outside of docker. try following the instruction in this
https://container-solutions.com/running-docker-in-jenkins-in-docker/